# Weak Derivatives and $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes

If I recall correctly, if we only know apriori that, say, $u\in L^1(\Omega)$ for some nice bounded domain $\Omega$ and we denote $u_h$ a sequence (as $h\to 0$) of regularizations of $u$, and we can show that $\partial_i u_h$ converges in $L^1$ to some function $v\in L^1$, then the conclusion is that $\partial_i u$ (with the derivative originally taken in the distributional sense) is in fact in $L^1$ as well (and hence $u\in W^{1,1}$). I think this is well established.

Now what if we're in a situation where we can show that all the second derivatives of $u_h$ (actual derivatives, since $u_h$ is smooth) converge to functions in $L^1$. Does it follow from this that in fact $u\in W^{2,1}$? The point is that nothing is said apriori about the first derivatives of $u_h$.

Edit: I just realized that a simple application of Gagliardo Nirenberg interpolation between the 0th and 2nd derivatives of $u_h$ would give us that the first derivatives $\partial_i u_h$ are cauchy in $L^1$ and give us an affirmative answer for my question. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you apply that theorem without assume you already are in $W^{2,1}$? Sorry, don't I see it.

Comment: You can apply it to $u_h$ and its derivatives, and by interpolation find that $\partial_i u_h$ is Cauchy in $L^1$ and from there conclude (from the first "theorem" I mentioned in my original post) that in fact $\partial_i u$ is also in $L^1$ and is equal to the $L^1$ limit of $\partial_i u_h$.

Comment: So are you saying, if $\partial_i\partial_j u$ exist weakly, you can conclude that $\partial_j u$ exists weakly?

Comment: Yep that seems to be the conclusion.

Comment: Mhm, that I know not to be true (at least in dimensions higher then two). Take for example the function $u(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1) + g(x_2)$. One has $\partial_1\partial_2 u = 0$ weak, but there is no need for either $\partial_1  f$ nor $\partial_2 g$ to exist weakly.

Comment: I think my conclusion requires all the second derivatives to exist weakly.

Comment: Okay, now I think I get it. You were refering to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality), I guess. And from this I agree with you. Because you know $D^2 u$ is in $L^1$, so $Du$ will be in $L^r$ for certain $r > 1$ but this of course implies for bounded $\Omega$ also the $L^1$ case. Since "weak = strong" this of course also implies when approximating. Thank you very much for this nice question!